# How to upload Excel files created by SSIS or .NET to SSRS report server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, reportingservices-2005

I have been given a task to generate a number of Excel files for our business and as a method of delivery I was considering SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services (SSRS).

What I want to do is either generate the Excel spreadshhets from SSIS or a .Net (C#/VB) application then programatically upload the file to the appropriate area within SSRS.

There does not appear to be any documentation for this so I'm not sure that this is supported but I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255428/load-ssrs-report-from-file-in-c-sharp-in-a-service) post which discusses report execution so was interested in other methods.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportExecution.ReportExecutionService rsExec = 
    new Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportExecution.ReportExecutionService();
    rsExec.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    rsExec.Url = @"http://<ServerName>/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx";
```

Does anyone have an experience in programatically uploading files to SSRS? Can you point me to any relevant articles?

Comment: Do you want to render the SSRS report into the excel using SSIS?

Comment: Not really, just enable the user to download it.

Comment: You can run the SSIS package using the SSRS and use the dataset prepared by SSIS. So that we can send the SSIS data to SSRS without any issues. Find article [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159215(v=sql.100).aspx). Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CreateResource method in the ReportingServices object model...  see a description of uploading PDF's programmatically [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/794982e4-e9a2-4328-92cd-bb2248ddbb8c/). You can then modify that to your requriements.